# Distinguishing clients based on certificate

Tags: biztalk, mtls

Will I be able to distinguish clients to my service in BizTalk orchestration based on mTLS client certificates? I need to route messages differently depending on who is calling me.

Are there any good methods of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Party Resolution Pipeline Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/party-resolution-pipeline-component)

> When the Party Resolution component reads the incoming message, it takes two message context properties as input: WindowsUser and SignatureCertificate. The WindowsUser property is populated by the adapter, or by a custom pipeline component, with the user name of the sender when it can reliably derive the sender information. The SignatureCertificate is populated by the adapter or the MIME/SMIME Decoder pipeline component with the thumbprint of the client authentication certificate.